# How call rest api with file in PowerBuilder

Tags: rest, httpclient, multipartform-data, powerbuilder

I works on PowerBuilder application and I need develop solution which call REST Apis

This Apis need several parameters and one file, with post method.

I do not found any sample of this.

Can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?
I've seen some implementations use a `OleObject` connected t to `MSXML2.XmlHttp`, fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which version of PowerBuilder you are using.  PowerBuilder 2017 R3 has an HTTPClient object as well as a RESTClient object and it supports Base64 encoding (what you would use to turn binary data into JSON compatible).  There are numerous code examples on the Appeon Website so rather than copy n' paste them all here suggest you look through those various examples and find one that meets your needs: https://community.appeon.com/index.php/codeexchange/powerbuilder?start=120